# IE Never finishes loading SharePoint page when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2007

I am working on a solution that loads SharePoint pages in a copy of IE. When the page finishes loading an event is triggered that executes some code in the application that wraps IE.

Now this all works fine and well, until JavaScript is turned off in the browser, a requirement for this solution (Don't ask). Naturally I don't expect the out of the box SharePoint user interface to be fully functional without JavaScript enabled, but although the web page is rendered correctly IE's progress bar never finishes the loading process. As a result my code is never triggered.

Try it for yourself.

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Disable JavaScript access for the Internet zone.
3. Navigate to a public SharePoint site [such as this one](http://www.sharepointcommunity.com/Site%20Pages/VendorDirectory.aspx).
4. Watch in amazement how the progress bar never finishes.

Does anyone have any idea about what is going on or if there are any workarounds?

Comment: Works for me, although it did take a good ten seconds loading an excessively large background image (spc_background.jpg), regardless of whether JavaScript was enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

After extensive testing there doesn't appear to be a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue that you are having is related to the specific SharePoint site.  They are more than likely loading something else in the background that is not part of the base install of SharePoint.

We have some internal sites running on SharePoint and I am able to get the progress bar to completely load with JavaScript disabled on all of them and they are standard installs.

I don't really have an answer as to what the other site might be loading to cause this, but my guess is that it is something that is not necessarily related to SharePoint.

Comment: I can reproduce it on (most) standard SharePoint sites as well. It is not related to this particular public URL. I just included it as people obviously cannot connect to our internal servers.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I was __not__ able to reproduce this on a SharePoint site that I manage.  I disabled JavaScript and the progress bar finished.  My guess is that there is an add-on of some sort in these SharePoint sites that is causing this to happen.